# pass object array to handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, associative-array

I have an associative array. I need to pass it to the handlebars template
Below is my code.

Javascript

```
    var arr1 = new Array();
        arr1['title'] = "title1";
        arr1['subt'] = "subtitle";

    getTemplate('popupTemplate1.html', arr1).done(function(data){
        $('#Data_popup').find('.popContent').html(data);
        $('#Data_popup').fadeIn(1000);
    })

function getTemplate( name,data){
  var d=$.Deferred();

  $.get(name,function(response){

    var template = Handlebars.compile(response);
    d.resolve(template(data))
  });

  return d.promise();  
}
```

Template structure is

```
<ul>
    <li>{{arr1.title}}</li>
    <li>{{arr1.subt}}</li>
</ul>
```

But this is not working. There is no output and if I check length of arr1, it gives me 0
I'm not getting how to reference array inside template
What I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply but I able to sort this issue.
I change the declaration of array to object as below,

```
var arr1 = new Object();
```

This way, now I'm able to access this object inside handlebar template as below,

```
<ul>
    <li>{{title}}</li>
    <li>{{subt}}</li>
</ul>
```

Anyways, thank you for the explanation.